# how to do not cover EditText when the input method show?

Tags: android, android-input-method

A button and a EditText and something else in my PopupWindow.
The button is at the bottom of the PopupWindow, but the TextView is not.
When the input method shows, I want to the button moves up but does not cover my EditText.
How can I do this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/white">
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view">
     <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
         ...
         <EditText/> <!-- This is the EditText -->
         ...
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_43_dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_17_dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_17_dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_11_dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_11_dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="OK"
        style="@style/NormalButton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Picture 2 is what i want.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you show your custom layout

Comment: when i checked your layout it works like you have wanted

Comment: check my changed layout in this room  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60744/sprytechiesandroid  check this

Comment: please check this and tell me is it fine or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dsa.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="OK" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="hjk" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

PLease try this hope it help u to solve your problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to set  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"**  in the activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml file. just like below

```
<activity
     android:name="com.src.personalhomemanager.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" >
</activity>
```

try this, may it will be help to you.

Comment: It does not work. I update my question and show my Layout there. I add "adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" and the button still covers my EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/white">
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ok_btn">
     <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
         ...
         <EditText/> <!-- This is the EditText -->
         ...
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/ok_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_43_dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_17_dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_17_dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_11_dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_11_dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="OK"
        style="@style/NormalButton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what to do. My code is the same as your suggestion.

Comment: i am trying to put your edit text layout above of ok button so that it will not overlap. Try above code snippet and lemme know...